# how to define time Field in laravel nova admin panel

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

i have time column in my data base . i need to defined field for this column.

this is my migration:

```
 $table->date('date');
            $table->time('time_begin');
            $table->time('time_Enable');
```

this is my resource:

```
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [

            datetime::make('time_Enable'),
            datetime::make('time_begin'),

        ];
    }
```

i just need  time  not date and time

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `extraAttributes` option with `type` key:

```
Text::make('time_begin')->withMeta(['extraAttributes' => ['type' => 'time']])
```

Answer (score 2):

Impressively enough, Nova not only doesn't have a Time field but also doesn't support a time-only usage of DateTime field.

On the other side, Nova has plenty of third parties componentes that can be easily added via composer. I did look for some on [Nova Packages](https://novapackages.com/) and found two viable options: [Laraning Time Field](https://novapackages.com/packages/laraning/nova-time-field) and [Michielfb Time Field](https://novapackages.com/packages/michielfb/laravel-nova-time-field), they seem to be pretty good and open-source.

Nonetheless, they have relatively few stars on GitHub and a rather old latest version, which is not much of a problem for such a simples functionality, but I'd rather go with a native one, so here is how I implemented it:

```
Text::make('Duration')
    ->placeholder('##:##:##')
    ->rules('date_format:"H:i:s"')
    ->help('hh:mm:ss'),
```

So basically I used the Text field with a format validation. Also added the placeholder and help attributes to make it a bit more intuitive. It works well! and I'm using it with a `time` database field. Other colleges suggested using a masked component but it would also require a third party one and I didn't find a good option.

Answer (score 1):

To work with time in nova 4, I did the following what is working fine for now.

```
DateTime::make('time_to')->displayUsing(function ($value) {
    return $value->format('H:i');
})->exceptOnForms(),

Text::make('time_to')->resolveUsing(function ($date) {
    $timestamp = new \DateTime($date);
    return $timestamp->format('H:i');
})->rules('date_format:"H:i"')->withMeta(['extraAttributes' => ['type' => 'time']])->onlyOnForms(),
```

Comment: Works the best - this should be the most voted-up answer as it solves the display in lists and on forms. Thx @Michel